# Front End design using Bootstrap and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to eclipse and worklight. I want to create front end using bootstrap. How can I do that using Eclipse. Please give me solution..

Answer (score 1):

This has got nothing to do with Eclipse? Eclipse is your IDE.

You need to review the Bootstrap documentation and implemented accordingly in your Worklight application.

You can also take a look at the Worklight Starter Application that was implemented using Bootstrap for the UI: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v630/StarterApplication_bootstrapProject.zip